# SSL Certificate cannot convert to GMT+7

Tags: python, ssl

I would like to ask how can I convert my SSL Certificate to datetime conversion at GMT +7

```
s = data['notAfter']
                        a = datetime.strptime(s, "%b %d %H:%M:%S %Y GMT").fromisoformat("Apr 11 23:59:59 2022 GMT")
                        tz = timezone(timedelta(hours=7))
                        new_time = a.astimezone(tz)
                        new_time == date
```

I've already try with some references, but it still doesn't work the time didn't want to convert. Is there any references that u would like to share? Thank you

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.